# Angular Material Chip not working with angular version 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, angular7

Angular Material Chip not working with angular version 7

**Tech**: Angular version 7, angular cli, angular material.

**Outcome I want:** I just want to use the angular material chip module.

**Things I've done:**

- I've installed "@angular/material": "^7.3.3", and @angular/animations": "^7.2.6",
- I've imported NoopAnimationsModule and MatChipsModule to my app module.

  **My imports in my app module:**

  import { NoopAnimationsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

  import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
  import { MatCommonModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';

**Then this is my component:**

```
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-chip-list #chipList>
              <mat-chip>Chip 1</mat-chip>
              <mat-chip>Chip 2</mat-chip>
            </mat-chip-list>
            <input [matChipInputFor]="chipList">
          </mat-form-field>
```

**Error I get:**

White screen when app running and this message in my code: **"mat-chip-list' is not a known element"**

Screen shot of my code and my browser:

[image]

Comment: Please create an [mcve] using https://stackblitz.com.

Comment: How did you import the MatChipsModule? Make sure it's from '@angular/material/chips' and not some place else (which for some reason happens with angular material sometimes)

Comment: @Grenther these are my imports :

import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';

Comment: I've added a screen shot to my question of what I see

Answer (score 3):

Here is a what your imports should look like.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NoopAnimationsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatCommonModule, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NoopAnimationsModule, MatChipsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,MatInputModule,MatCommonModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is an [stackblitz of your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcgufw)

Comment: Thank you, I've added your changes and still get a white screen. Could this be something to do with angular cli or angular 7 ?

Comment: @AngularM - check your dependencies. You should also have `@angular/cdk`. But there should be no conflict with angular 7 as that is what my stackblitz is and also no conflict with the cli. Your angular version and material version do have to be compatible (both 7 if you want 7).

Comment: @AngularM - also check your browser console for errors. Finally remove the html around the chilist to ensure there is nothing else preventing it from being rendered.

Comment: I've just npm i @angular/cdk as I didnt have that. I still have a white screen and no console errors. see screenshot above Igor

Comment: Igor - when I remove <mat-form-field> from the html my app runs fine

Comment: @AngularM - you need `import {MatCommonModule, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';` for that. Also don't forget to include a reference to the css (I did not do that in the stackblitz)

Comment: I've imported all of those and still white screen

Comment: @AngularM - it is hard to say why that would happen without a [mcve]. Check the generated HTML on the page in the browser's debugger (Elements tab in Chrome) and check if you can see anything there and possibly inspect the elements to see if there is some css that is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Include MatChipsModule in 'exports' of your NgModule

```
import {MatCommonModule, MatInputModule, MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   ...
 ],
 exports: [
   ...,
   MatChipsModule
 ]
})
```